# Merge files in Azure Blob using powershell

Tags: powershell, azure

I have a requirement to Merge multiple files with same keyword having different timestamp in Azure blobs and move them from one folder to another so that downstream service can consume them.

I was able to move the files from one folder to other but I don't find an option to concatenate them using powershell (With in Blob folders) into one single file. Is there any way to achieve this specifically using powershell ?

Note: All files in the folder are text/csv files with same layout.

Comment: Please give some samples of code you have written and explain which parts do not give the expected result. Please read the SO guidelines before posting.

Comment: Azure blob service doesn't offer file system I/O operations (unless you're using Azure Files). Any manipulation you do would need to take place in your app, with the local resources your app is operating within (memory/disk/etc). Doesn't matter the file type. As written, this question is very broad (lots of ways to perform file merges), with no specific programming question.

Comment: I was more inclined to Powershell as we have a third party scheduler from where we need to automate the merging and file movement. we already have other filer operations performed using Powershell so it is easy to plug.
If there is any best approach. Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

Copy Blob operation cannot concatenate/join/combine blobs, it’s intended as a background copy operation and can only make "copies" the destination blob will be overwritten each time

There you may use case it will require the content of all the required blobs to be retrieved, a new blob constructed locally and then uploaded to destination

get-azurestorageblobcontent will bring down the blob content

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-powershell#download-blobs  Concatenate Locally

Upload blobs to the container: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-powershell#upload-blobs-to-the-container